# How to bring up an interviewers research in an interview for a post-doc position?

Tags: interview

I am applying for a post-doc position with a PI whose research I have cited in my publication and I have actually found very useful for my knowledge. I want to bring this up in an interview to highlight that our research interests overlap very well. But I do not want to sound too flattering. How should I bring this up in the interview?

Answer (score 3):

If you talk about your research and you used the interviewer's work or found it helpful, you can say so as an aside without sounding too flattering. A statement like "I actually learned this concept from you." is factual and not overblown. Similar for "I used your technique from ISCA 1990". Good luck with your interview.